# Hydrate joined Entities with Api-Platform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I m building my first rest API with Api-Platform for an AngularJs app,

I want to get all my Project entity like juste here (with my url /projects):

```
{
  "@context": "/contexts/Project",
  "@id": "/projects",
  "@type": "hydra:PagedCollection",
  "hydra:totalItems": 19,
  "hydra:itemsPerPage": 30,
  "hydra:firstPage": "/projects",
  "hydra:lastPage": "/projects",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/projects/1",
      "@type": "Project",
      "name": "test1",
      "parent": null,
      "createdAt": "2014-12-22T11:38:13+01:00",
      "updatedAt": null,
      "deletedAt": null
    },
    {
      "@id": "/projects/2",
      "@type": "Project",
      "name": "test2",
      "parent": null,
      "createdAt": "2014-12-22T17:02:50+01:00",
      "updatedAt": null,
      "deletedAt": null
    },
    {
      "@id": "/projects/3",
      "@type": "Project",
      "name": "test3",
      "parent": "/projects/2",
      "createdAt": "2014-12-22T18:28:50+01:00",
      "updatedAt": null,
      "deletedAt": null
    }
  ]
}
```

But as you can see my Projects can have parent, so I got a reference of my parent Project ( like this /projects/2 )

Can I get directly a Project Object in Json instead of reference like this ?

```
    {
        "@id": "/projects/3",
        "@type": "Project",
        "name": "test3",
        "parent": {
            "@id": "/projects/2",
            "@type": "Project",
            "name": "test2",
            "parent": null,
            "createdAt": "2014-12-22T17:02:50+01:00",
            "updatedAt": null,
            "deletedAt": null
        },
        "createdAt": "2014-12-22T18:28:50+01:00",
        "updatedAt": null,
        "deletedAt": null
    }
```

This is a good pratical of Rest APi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Platform has a built-in function for [embedding relations in the parent JSON document](https://api-platform.com/doc/1.0/api-bundle/serialization-groups-and-relations#embedding-relations).

Your entity will look like:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class Project
{
   private $id;

   /** @Groups({"embed"}) */
   private $parent;

   /** @Groups({"embed"}) */
   private $name;

   /** @Groups({"embed"}) */
   private $createdAt;

   // ...
}
```

And the service definition:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    # ...

    resource.offer:
        parent:    api.resource
        arguments: [ 'AppBundle\Entity\Offer' ]
        calls:
            -      method:    initNormalizationContext
                   arguments: [ { groups: [ embed ] } ]
        tags:      [ { name: api.resource } ]
```

Be careful, it will embed the parent as well as the parent of the parent and so on. If you want to change this, you need to create a custom normalizer. It will be more straightforward when Symfony 3.1 will be released thanks to [the new `@MaxDepth` annotation](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/17113).

Comment: I try this but it doesn't change anything when I call it, it still some url format and not an embed format. Did I need to change some configuration ?

Comment: Ok after do a composer update of my project it's works thanks !